# What is this math font and how do I access it?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I'm reading a paper that uses a font that looks like this for equations:

[image]

It looks a bit like Times New Roman. In my file, I use `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` and get the following really ugly looking result:

[image]

So I'm wondering what the difference is. I know in the first one the subscripts aren't italicized and I can easily change that in mine, but i still want to use the particular font in the model example.

Comment: Do you have the paper as a pdf? http://blog.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/extracting-font-information-from-pdf-files_35/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An extensive list of maths fonts can be found [here](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf). It looks like the font might be Belleek math from the package [`mathtime`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathtime).

If you have the PDF, you might be able to find the name of the font by checking the properties of the document (shortcut `CTRL+D`) and looking under the fonts tab. There will be a list of all fonts included in the PDF.

Comment: I imagine ctrl+d is not only OS-specific (which is definitely true), but also viewer-specific?

Comment: @cfr Good point. The shortcut mentioned is for Adobe Reader.